# Cardinality of the set of chains of $(\mathcal P(\mathbb N), \subseteq)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, cardinals

In [that article](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/uncountable-chain-of-subsets-of-the-natural-numbers/), I describe some chains of $(\mathcal P(\mathbb N), \subseteq)$. Some of those are having the cardinality of the continuum.

As for any permutation of $\mathbb Q$, we can define in a one-to-one way a chain (having the cardinality of the continuum) of $(\mathcal P(\mathbb N), \subseteq)$ using Dedekind cuts, we have at least a continuum of chains of $(\mathcal P(\mathbb N), \subseteq)$.

But at the end, what is the cardinality of the set chains of $(\mathcal P(\mathbb N), \subseteq)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your chain of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$; any subset of that is a chain. That gives $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ chains.

Comment: Thanks for this! And do you have an argument to conclude that $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ is the cardinality of $S$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Since $\operatorname{card}(\mathcal P (\mathcal P(\mathbb N))) = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ there are at most $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ many chains.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Each chain is an element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)))$.